# Flowtype not updating when maximize or minimize

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Flowtype is acting odd, if i load the page when screen is not maximized and then maximize the font still the same size of when page is loaded, then if i restore this to not be in maximized it get the font-size of what should be when miximized. But if i resize the window with my mouse on edges, the  Flowtype update with the right size. Is that a bug or i'm missing something with javascript? I'm calling flowtype with options when page is loaded. If i move the code to call flowtype on resize flowtype doesnt work. I'm using it on my portfolio page and it's hosted on my house so i can't leave any link for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the bug was removed on update v1.1. Just update.